# How to remove header and footer from specific pages?

Tags: php, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop website where I have header for whole page

I want header or footer to be hidden in a specific page eg shopping-cart

Here is my shopping cart page link http://localhost:8080/index.php?controller=order-opc#box-order-one

Here is how I tried to hide header inside shopping-cart.tpl

```
{if $page_name != 'box-order-one'}<div class="nav-tabs"></div>{/if}
```

But this does not work, what do I need to do to get what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy and fast way is through CSS.

For PS 1.6 (default theme):

```
body#order .header-container,
body#order .footer-container,
body#order-opc .header-container,
body#order-opc .footer-container {
  display: none !important;
}
```

For PS 1.7 (default theme):

```
body#checkout #header,
body#checkout #footer {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: It's not a good solution because the code will be still parsed on all pages and this can provide to conflicts especially if you have any commercials in the hidden code

Comment: Hii alexander , Inside order-pc i have 4 boxes, #box-order-one, #box-order-two, #box-order-three, #box-order-four,  am using hash to navigate to those boxes inside a shopping car(order-opc)t , i want the navs to be hiddenonly in shopping cart, ur method hide in all orders related pages

Answer (score 1):

You can wrap your content which you want to exclude into the condition

```
{if isset($page_name) && !$page_name|in_array:['order', 'authentication', 'address']}
    // the code you want to exclude
{/if}
```

inside in_array function list all pages on which the code will be excluded. Be sure that you use the correct name of pages, you can check it out within dev tools. Look what id a page  has on a current page and use it.